# What's the type of React Query's Error and how to handle different cases?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, error-handling, react-query

I'm using React Query with typescript to fetch data in my project and I'm trying to use the error the useQuery hook returns to display a message describing the error if it exists like this :

```
{isError && (error)? <p className=" text-[#ff0000] text-center font-semibold">{error?.response.data.message}</p> : null}
```

I'm having a problem with the error type :
[image]

How can I fix it, I couldn't find anything on the internet and if possible can anyone explain how to handle different thrown error with react query since you can throw anything in JS/TS

Comment: The answer depends on what else are you using. By default, without any other library, the error would be an Error, but since you are accessing `error.response`, it looks like you are using something like axios maybe? In that case, the `error` would be whatever axios `throw`s on error.

Comment: @JakubKotrs yeah I'm using axios actually. can you please explain what do you mean by whatever axios throws on error? I'm kind of new to typescript and I don't usually deal with error handling

Comment: https://axios-http.com/docs/handling_errors, the error that is in `catch` here is the error you are getting, find it's type.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

`error` defaults to type `unknown` because your `queryFn` can throw anything, that's a javascript behaviour. `throw 5` will give you `number` as your error type. There is no good way to assert that, so unknown is the best possible type. It's also what TypeScript does now per default since v4.4 ([useUnknownInCatchVariables](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/typescript/announcing-typescript-4-4/#use-unknown-catch-variables))

The best way to make sure that your app runs as you want is to narrow the type at runtime. `if (error instanceof Error)` does the trick, and the you can safely access `error.message`.

If you are using `axios`, the type is actually an `AxiosError`, and axios has an `axios.isAxiosError(error)` helper that checks for that and also narrows the type correctly.

The alternative is to provide generics to useQuery:

```
useQuery<Todo[], AxiosError>(['todos'], fetchTodos)
```

but this is bad for a couple of reasons:

1. there are actually four generics, and you remove a bunch of features by only providing two of them
2. There is no guarantee that your error will *really* be an axios error. For example, if you use `select`, and a runtime error happens in there (because of some faulty logic), your error will be a "normal" `Error`, but not an axios Error.

---

Alas, as you can throw anything in JS, unknown is the most correct type.

I'm also going into more details in my blog:

https://tkdodo.eu/blog/react-query-and-type-script

Answer (score 3):

As @TkDodo has pointed out, you could provide generics to `useQuery` but it's not worth it, since you will lose the Type inference too.

However, as a workaround, I add the `onError` callback and type its `error` arg instead. TypeScript will infer the type of that error to the type I am expecting from `useQuery`.

Note that I am using `Axios` request & response interceptors for all requests that I use to format and throw my custom errors.

---

Example...

```
interface IPayload {
  someKey: string; // ETC
}

// The type of error expected from the response (also formatted by interceptor).
interface IApiError {
  message: string;
  description: string;
  statusCode: string | number;
}

export const useMyQuery = (payload: IPayload) => {
  const { data, isLoading, isError, error, refetch } = useQuery({
    queryKey: ['some', 'query-keys'],
    queryFn: () => API.fetchMyData(payload),
    // This does the trick
    onError: (err: IApiError) => err,
  });
};
```

Answer (score 1):

My solution is too simple, so you can find out about the answer, but only for Axios:

```
const {
  data: location,
  isLoading: isLocationLoading,
  isError: isLocationError,
} = useQuery(
  {
    queryKey: ['location', user?.partner?.tourId],
    queryFn: () => getLocation('d'),
    onError: (err: AxiosError) => {
      console.log('Произошла ошибка при запросе:', err.response?.status)
    },
  }
)
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I just used the  `as Error` type assertion like this

```
<p>{(mutation.error as Error).message)}</p>
```

In your case, you can try

```
{isError && (error as Error)? <p className=" text-[#ff0000] text-center font-semibold">{(error as Error)?.response.data.message}</p> : null}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just add instanceof Error

```
if (error instanceof Error) return <div>{error.message }</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue with Typescript and react-query, same error `Object is of type 'unknown'.`

Installing this devDependency "**@types/react-query**" helped me somehow. I am using VS Code editor and I think that helped with type suggestions. This might help.

`npm i --save-dev @types/react-query`

Answer (score 0):

**For Mutation only:**

If you are using Axios for Api calls, use the following to get Axios type errors:

```
const error = mutation.error as AxiosError;
```

Now, the `error` object will not throw any `object not found` warning.